# Unable to load dynamic library :WAMP

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - Le module spécifié est introuvable.
I wantto install composer for php..tried to fix the problem with solutions i had found but didnt work

Comment: Do you have that file? Can you check in that location?

Comment: yes i have it and i also checked if extension=php_intl.dll exist in php.ini, is there other causes for this issue

Comment: I would say it's better you use [Vagrant by HashiCorp](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [Scotch Box ♥ A Vagrant LAMP/LEMP Stack for Beginners That Just Works](https://box.scotch.io/).

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment yet - sorry)

Go to your `routes/web.php` file and put `phpinfo();` in there somewhere.

Reload your site and you should see the php.ini your application is using.
(Loaded Configuration File)

Then go modify THAT php.ini around line 998.

`extension=php_intl.dll`

edit: If you're using homestead or vagrant etc. You'll have to SSH into your VM and modify the php.ini found in phpinfo.

Comment: the problem is that everytime i restart wamp i got this error "Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll'"